# Path Integral Measure Transformation as $(DetU)^{-1}$

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, integration, fermions, grassmann-numbers

The path integral measure transforms as $D\Psi\rightarrow (DetU)^{-1}D\Psi$ for fermions, with $DetU=J$ the Jacobian.
I am referring to *Peskin and Schroeder's Introduction to Quantum Field Theory, Chapter 19* about chiral anomalies.
What is the intuition behind the path integral measure transforming by the inverse of the determinant for fermions? Is this just by definition/convemtion? I am struggling to see the significance of this choice.

Comment: A very detailed derivation of this can be found in section 2.4, "fermionic path integrals", of these lecture notes: https://people.phys.ethz.ch/~babis/Teaching/QFT1/qft2.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grassmannian integrals satisfy (this is a definition)
$$
\int d \theta \theta = 1 \tag{1}
$$
Let $\theta' = A \theta$. Then,
$$
1 = \int d \theta' \theta' = \int d (A\theta) (A\theta) = A \int d (A\theta) \theta
$$
Consistency with (1) then requires
$$
d(A\theta) = \frac{1}{A} d \theta.
$$

On the other hand, bosonic integrals satisfy
$$
\int dx x \sim x^2 \tag{2}
$$
Let $x'=Ax$. Then,
$$
x'^2 \sim \int dx' x' \implies (Ax)^2 \sim \int d(Ax) (Ax) \implies x^2 \sim \frac{1}{A} \int d(Ax) x
$$
Consistency with (2) requires
$$
d(Ax) = A dx.
$$
The generalization to multiple variables $\theta \to \theta_i$, $x \to x_i$ and $A \to \det A$ can be easily checked.